# My MVC app using EF6 started throwing an error about code generate from an EDMX file?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

An in-development ASP.Net MVC app that was working fine until today has now started throwing the following error:

> The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was
>   generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First
>   development.

The data layer of this app was done completely in Code-first. There are not any EDMX files of any sort involved. I am using Migrations.

My connection string is

```
<add name="MicroContentContext" 
connectionString="Data Source=MdDB;
Initial Catalog=MyCaatalog;
Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What has gone wrong and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: What changed - look in your source control

Comment: Are you using an EntityConnection connection string by mistake?

Comment: The only thing I did to my code was add another class and the appropriate  DbSet to my context class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944596/entity-framework-cant-use-the-dbcontext-model-being-created

Comment: Erik That refers to a situation where an EDMX file is involved or used at some point. As my question states EDMX files never were involved in this project.